# How many points are required to fix at most one curve in $\mathbb{A}^2$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Will it be true that given $\frac{d(d+3)}{2}$ different points in the plane $\mathbb{A}^2$, these points determine at most one curve of degree $d$ passing through those points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't true without some sort of general position condition on the points: two suitable plane cubics intersect in nine points, but according to your formula, $9$ points should determine a cubic. If you do apply the correct general position argument, then it is true, and a proof is outlined in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic#Generalizations).

Comment: Thx. How should I interpret the condition "general position"?

Comment: The intuition should be that for "most" collections of points (ie some Zariski-dense open subset of the space parameterizing the collection of all such points), this is true. The specific details in this situation is that the condition "$f(p)=0$" determines a linear condition on the coefficients of $f$, and saying that the points are in general position in this case means that all these relations are independent.